# Grouping for similar level groups in RTF in Oracle EBS for reports

Tags: xml, oracle, grouping, rtf

```
<LIST_G_SETUP> 
<G_SETUP> 
<COMPANY_NAME>My Company</COMPANY_NAME>
-<LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS> 
-<G_TRANSACTIONS> 
<INVOICE_NUMBER>123456</INVOICE_NUMBER>
<LIST_G_SALESREPS> 
-<G_SALESREPS> 
<SALES_TRX_ID>654321</SALES_TRX_ID> 
<LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
</G_SALESREPS>
-<G_SALESREPS>
<SALES_TRX_ID>52375</SALES_TRX_ID> 
<LINE_NO>2</LINE_NO>
</G_SALESREPS> 
</LIST_G_SALESREPS>
-<LIST_G_LINES> 
-<G_LINES>
<LN_LINE_NUMBER>1</LN_LINE_NUMBER> 
<LN_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINE_ID>145926</LN_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINE_ID>
</G_LINES> 
-<G_LINES> 
<LN_LINE_NUMBER>2</LN_LINE_NUMBER>
<LN_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINE_ID>945872</LN_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINE_ID>
</G_LINES>
</G_TRANSACTIONS> 
</LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS>
</G_SETUP> 
</LIST_G_SETUP>
```

Now Required output is

```
INVoice Number|SalesTrxId| LineNo.| LineNumber| CUstomerTrxLine
123456           654321       1         1           145926
123456           52375        2         2           945872
```

How I should put the for loop in rtf to get the required output?
I am running this as a CP in Oracle and unable to get required output.
It would be really helpful if you can show the required rtf for the same including for loops in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and where you are struggeling with it

Comment: Hi Skynet! I tried different using different for loops. Like in one I have open the groups in this order F(G_SETUP) F(G_Transactions)F(G_SALESREPS) (Now column names) Invoice number| SalesTrxID| Line NO.| E(end for each)E(end for each)E(end for each) F(G_lines)CustomerTrxLine E()end for each. In this the 1st 4 columns are populating data but not the last one.